# AS3 (or any language) trig library for triangles?

Tags: actionscript-3, trigonometry

Does anyone know of a library for easily dropping in parameters of angles and lengths of sides, and letting it automagically extrapolate the non-given angles and lengths using trig?  Even if it had lame performance, it would be very useful for prototyping, and performance could be optimized (even supplying table lookup and the sort).  If nothing like that is out there, I will probably write it.

Thanks,
umop

Answer (score 1):

It'll be tough to find a library because trig is so simple, you just need to do a quick formula.

```
   a^2 + b^2 = c^2

   s=o/h c=a/h t=o/a
```

I'm thinking writing your own function to do these chores would be very very quick :)